# How to disable mouse click when hover on Manjaro

Tags: manjaro, kde-plasma

I am newbee for Manjaro. I installed Manjaro on Raspberry Pi4 with touch screen. Somehow today my mouse started to click when hover on a clickable component. I want to disable this feature but couldn’t find how to do, either how the feature was activated. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my searches I found that problem is about a thirdparty software onboard. Onboard is activating mousetweaks software and this cause the problem. I removed mousetweaks by this code and problem solved:
`pamac remove mousetweaks` and reboot.